# getScript in noconflict-mode

Tags: jquery, getscript

Due to Wordpress loading jQuery in nonconflict-mode, I must wrap my scripts inside `jQuery(function($){...})`

The parent script executes as expected.
However, I conditionally load a 2nd script via getScript:

```
$.getScript('js/2nd.js').done(function() {
   editElem();
});
```

Do I also need to wrap everything inside "2nd.js"? If I don't do it, nothing happens - not even an error is thrown in Chromes console. If I wrap it, it says "editElem is not defined" - although my "2nd.js" of course defines it.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: I had the same issue some months ago. My solution was, defining the function (editElem in your case) like var tmpFnc = new Function('alert(\'hello\')'); and call tmpFnc after script is loaded using tmpFnc(); . This works like eval('alert(\'hello\')'); Hope this may help you a bit.

Comment: wow, that's not really pretty? My 2nd.js has a whole lot of big functions in it...

Comment: May be you have any runtime conflict. I looked into a current project code. I have a couple of functions, which are necessary depending of users permissions. The $.getScript is triggered by another previous function like this... function login_action(){
 $.getScript('core/login/login_action.js.php');
 login_display_fadeout();
} and this works. Don't worry about the .php, it generates javascript output.

Comment: and this is running in noconflict-mode? I have no problems outside of noconflict-mode!

Comment: R U using two different libraries using $ ?

Comment: no, jQuery in non-conflict-mode. I still don't understand if you have your 2nd script "wrapped" or not

Comment: May be the entire code must be loaded inside of a <script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
... code ...
});
</script> But I am not sure. Good luck.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean (and documented above) by "wrapping"... Thanks anyway!

Comment: please be back with results, if it is working or not, thanks

Comment: I will. It would help if you would upvote the question as it seems I'm not alone with the problem. Thanks!

Comment: with pleasure, will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to still wrap it — the goal of noconflict mode is to keep your code working even if the `$` variable is taken by another library. As you've discovered, though, your global functions are no longer global once they're inside a closure!

Globals are not considered JavaScript's finest achievement, and this case is a good example; module loaders like RequireJS (which can perhaps be [extended for lazy loading](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy)?) can make life easier down the road.

That said, if you only have two files and just want to export your functions from `2nd.js`, you can do that without any extra libraries:

```
(function ($) {
    // ... define your functions
    function editElem () {
    }
    function otherFunc () {
    }
    function privateFunc () {
    }

    // export any functions needed by scripts outside this file.
    window.LazyUtils = {
        editElem: editElem,
        otherFunc: otherFunc
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

After that you should be able to call `LazyUtils.editElem()` from your first JS file, the console, or wherever. Up to you what to name that module - "LazyUtils" is just an example.

Comment: Don, I have to try that asap. Thank you!